# How to retrieve html with grequests

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, python-requests, grequests

When I was just doing some research on python web scraping I got to know of a package named grequests, it was said that this can send parallel HTTP requests thus gaining more speed than the normal python requests module. Well, that sounds great but I was not able to get the HTML of the web pages I requested as there is no .text method like the normal requests module. If I get some help it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Since `grequests.imap` function returns a list, you'll need to use an index or call the entire list in a loop.

```
responses = grequests.imap(session)
for response in responses:
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Hi IwasBachus, welcome to Stack Overflow! I went ahead and edited your post to be more legible. Please take the time in the future to write clear, formatted posts.